# How to create HTML in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have been working on React for a year. Now, I am writing angular. How can I create a piece of html code in ts.file?

In react, I do it that way:

```
const example = (item: string): React.ReactNode => {
  return <p> something.... {item} </p>
}
```

I want to do same thing in Angular8+

I know some way to do it. For example:

```
const example2= (name: string): string => {
  return `
    <div>  
       <p>heyyy ${name}</p>
    </div>
  `;
};
```

Are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Have you read the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/what-is-angular)? Have you setup an angular project on your machine?

Comment: I have not read whole Docs yet. I have a project on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular, there are a couple of ways to do this. If you need to generate HTML in the typescript and then interpolate it into the template, you can use a combination of the `DomSanitizer` and the `innerHTML` attribute into other elements (for example a `span`).

Below would be an example of what I suggested above:

`hello-world.component.ts`:

```js
@Component({
    selector: "hello-world",
    templateUrl: "./hello-world.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./hello-world.component.scss"]
})
export class HelloWorld {
   innerHTML: string = `<p>Hello, world!</p>`;
}
```

`sanitze.pipe.ts`:

```js
@Pipe({
   name='sanitize'
})
export class SanitizePipe {
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
   transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
   }
}
```

`hello-world.component.html`:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="innerHTML | sanitize"</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, I would checkout the docs too. You shouldn't be injecting HTML like that often. Interpolation is your friend!